# Pallet Rack Size does not update if using pick-up

Tags: anylogic

I know that for an object to be removed from a pallet rack you need "Rack Pick". However, in one of my models, I have a different configuration where I am using pick up:

**Step 1: 10 agents are in the rack**

[image]

**Step 2: Another agent picks them up**
[image]

The way AnyLogic understands the above is that the rack still holds 10 agents, so I get the error eventually that the pallet rack is full. Is there a simple turnaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove the agents from cells with this line of code

```
palletRack.remove(agent);
```

put it to your pickup block, "on pickup" trigger.