# Pallets should wait in the rack to be picked up by another agent Truck instead of getting destroyed with Sink block

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

Here is the scenario I'm trying to model.

A population of agent Container is generated at a unloading dock, it carried to storage area 1 where it is placed randomly in pallet racks. Then, it is carried to storage area 2 where the containers are arranged depending on two criteria:
i) Containers that are to be carried by Truck is placed on one palletRack and conatiners to be carried by Train on another.
ii) Containers are also arranged on the basis of weight; heavy containers are placed at the bottom & light containers are placed at the top.

Then Trucks/Trains come to storage area 2 to pickup the containers and time taken to load containers to the truck/train is recorded.

My approach can be found here: [my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5mAd.png). In the last delay block of Container process flow I am injecting one Truck.(on enter: sourceTruck.inject(1))

The error I'm getting now is 'agent not found in pallet rack' when truck comes to pickup the container. I want the containers to wait in storage area 2 for pick up by truck/train instead of getting destroyed. (May be it gets destroyed after a certain period of time or something). How can I achieve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a different approach because it's the agent that is being racked and picked. So in your second flowchart, it's not logical that the truck is being picked, the truck is actually picking. Also, you are right, the sink does not work well.

I suggest you use the configuration shown in the question at the link below (look at the answer as well since you'll need to use the remove function to remove the agent from the rack):

[Pallet Rack Size does not update if using pick-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753762/pallet-rack-size-does-not-update-if-using-pick-up)